# How To Make A Widget Just Stick To Bottom Of Page

Tags: flutter

I am trying to build a view as in the image below.
The *tweet your reply* is just stack at the bottom while the other stuff are scrollable.
I've been banging my head on how to achieve this for a couple of hours.
Exactly;y like in the image below. There are four sections:

1. The post (tweet)
2. The row of icons
3. The comments (which scrolls)
4. The tweet your reply which is static

[image]

Comment: Multiple ways, it would help if you describe what framework you are trying to do this in as I thought this was Android but the tag says flutter

Comment: Yes this is Flutter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution would be to use the [`Align`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html) Widget. So in your `Stack` you would put as the last element in the stack:

```dart
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
  child: // your widget would go here
),
```

I'm judging by your question that you have figured out how to do all of the other parts, and was just wondering about the bottom part. You can use `Align` to align things in other ways as well (such as topCenter, bottomLeft, etc). Hope this helps, and if so please up vote and accept as answer and if not leave a comment below.

---

**Edit:**
I wouldn't use a `Stack`. I would wrap the entire widget tree in a `Column`, and put the post in a `Expanded` Widget with a flex factor of 1, and a `Row` of Icons below it. Then put a `ListView` in an `Expanded` Widget with a flex of 4 (you can experiment with values). And lastly in the `Column` I would add you "Tweet you reply" Widget.

Simple layout code to give you an idea of how to implement it:

```dart
Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: <Widget>[
              //your post
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: <Widget>[
                  // your icons
                ],
              ),

              //your comments
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: // you textField,
        ),
      ],
    )
```

Comment: @marvinralph , I updated my answer to give a brief outline of what your Widget structure should look like.

Comment: I still couldnt figure out how to solve this, both approach seemed as though they would work but it didnt.

Currently this is my code now, and i still have the bottom input scrolling with the view instead of being static at the bottom:

Comment: @marvinralph check to make sure your bottom input is outside of the ListView, but inside the column in the align widget.

Comment: can you give me a structure on how the whole view should look like
Something like this: 
-stack
  - align
     column

etc

Comment: Thank You your solution worked perfectly, i just made a slight edit to your answer. Thank you soo much you've really saved my ass.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(50),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        "A POST"
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(Icons.details),
                      Icon(Icons.print),
                      Icon(Icons.translate),
                      Icon(Icons.map)
                    ],
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView(
                      children: List.generate(10, (index) => ListTile(title: Text("Comment $index"),)),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Tweet your reply"
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The output:

[image]

If you want the post to scroll with it, this should help

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(50),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          "A POST"
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(Icons.details),
                        Icon(Icons.print),
                        Icon(Icons.translate),
                        Icon(Icons.map)
                      ],
                    ),
                    Column(
                      children: List.generate(10, (index) => ListTile(title: Text("Comment $index"),)),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Tweet your reply"
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Amazing, this is exactly what i want, thanks @Josteve Adekanbi

Comment: I want the posts part to scroll with the comments lists, but from your solution above i cant achieve that